# Are any of you interested in starting an online LaTeX course?

Tags: discussion, community

What are your feelings about this?  I got this inspiration by the courses the MIT and Harvard are giving online nowadays.

I took the introduction to electronics of the MIT, and I must say they are pretty good.  Maybe some of you, like me, think this could be a good way to promote LaTeX use and at the same time instruct/refresh knowledge of LaTeX with a worldwide reach?

Comment: Remember these universities financial model is much different from TUG, at the same time it's good wish and possible with collective effort.

Comment: I would just further beef up the LaTeX Wikibook.  That thing is already hella popular.

Comment: Commercial book writers might disagree with this idea.

Comment: @Mario It will help others to visualise what you mean, if you can add a sample video/screenshot/url link for MIT and Harvard courses. Some are getting confused with books,text tutorials. I think you mean this https://www.edx.org/ right ?

Comment: @texenthusiast yeap, exactly.  When I took it (a year ago or so) there only was the one from MIT.

Comment: @texenthusiast Unfortunately, I didn't see any of the videos of the course in the edx.org webpage.  I looked for them on youtube and they arent't there either...

Comment: @SeanAllred I would recommend **first** genuine authored [lshort-multilingual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort) OR [ltxprimer-1.0 -Typesetting quality](http://www.tug.org/twg/mactex/tutorials/ltxprimer-1.0.pdf) since wikibook is [not fully peer reviewed-75 % red sections](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) atleast for now and may contain bad contagious practices  . May be after a while it reaches stable.

Comment: @texenthusiast Hence the beefing up, but nice links!

Answer (score 15):

The main problem with screencast video tutorials is broken links over time except when hosted by TeX organisations(tug.org or ctan.org) like [George Gratzer's author of Math into La­TeX 4th Edi­tion](http://www.ctan.org/author/gratzer) [Video presentations link](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/examples/Math_into_LaTeX-4/mil4-video-presentations.zip) .

I can post personal video links today but over time unfortunately for whatever reason the video tutorials become inactive unless well maintained and taken over by decent TeX organisations. I will give for three genuine individual people whom i don't known but they are math teachers and graduate engg student have done excellent job on videos. They are not known to me but which i have followed them during my starting days. some of them are at comp.tex.tex.

**[Computer Musings by Professor Donald E. Knuth](http://scpd.stanford.edu/knuth/index.jsp)**

--> Go to `Other Videos` section (one may find many more..)

- Five-session short courses about TeX (1981)

  [TeX For Beginners: - Session 1-5](http://myvideos.stanford.edu/player/slplayer.aspx?coll=dcc0b290-ead5-48ea-b3d6-e54f3efd0c36&co=9b15b9da-e4ac-44bc-bc7f-58d040677ea1&o=true)
- Twelve lectures about the implementation of TeX (1982)

  [The Internal Details of TeX82 - Session 1-12](http://myvideos.stanford.edu/player/slplayer.aspx?coll=dcc0b290-ead5-48ea-b3d6-e54f3efd0c36&co=55dabc2d-da7e-4aca-8fdc-0dbe4835b894&o=true)

**Some Online Resources:**

- [Sharelatex](https://www.sharelatex.com) [Beginners Video Tutorial](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/latex-guides/beginners-tutorial.html#.UjXFpFFDsyQ) and its [full list of tutorial videos](http://www.youtube.com/user/ShareLaTeX/videos?view=0&sort=da&live_view=500&flow=list) as mentioned by JosephWright at his [blog](http://www.texdev.net/2013/09/15/latex-tutorial-videos-from-sharelatex/)
- [Writelatex videos](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnC5h3PY-znygZ2rYNaX7_8j2Duwh58cK) (links provided by Madam barbara beeton in comments) and its https://www.writelatex.com/templates/
- [LaTeX Tutorial by Joe DiNoto](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDD406480D35CE390)
- [LaTeX Tutorials by Mrs Krummel](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1D4EAB31D3EBC449)
- [A LaTeX weblog of video tutorial series by Sourav Singhal](http://quicklatex.blogspot.com).

Notable mentions are

- [TUG videos](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/?s=TUG+2011)
- [Six LaTeX tools (with videos) (Portuguese)](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2010-1/reinaldo-videos/)
- [UK-TUG videos](http://vimeo.com/uktug)
  *Note: The Vimeo videos were done using iMovie to combine the slides with   recordings made using Audacity by [Joseph Wright](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9040329#9040329)*
- [River-valley Video tutorials(not so basic on LaTeX)](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/category/video-tutorials/)

PS: I am sorry incase i have posted these links and could not provide others(as i am not aware). I presented these links to help others.I am open to any feedback.

Comment: To incorporate best-practices in LaTeX coding and keep pace with latest packages in video examples is a big challenge not yet done and hence TeX.SX.

Comment: Exactly, a video is not as easily (collaboratively) editable as a Wiki.

Comment: @texenthusiast -- many thanks for posting these links!  i had been trying to locate the original knuth tex videos; there was once a copy at the tug office, but it can no longer be found, and someone had recently asked me about it.  it's great to know that they're still available, and from the location where they were originally recorded.  you've definitely made my day!

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks Madam, for the kind words. :). I found those links by chance rather than by purpose while searching for something else on knuth. Thought it would useful to all community and hence updated them.

Comment: i've just learned of another group of intro latex videos via a comment on the linkedin tex/latex user group list: (http://www.linkedin.com/groupAnswers?viewQuestionAndAnswers=&discussionID=273967952&gid=1600297&trk=EMLt_anet_qa_ttle&fromEmail=&ut=02WXI0rTisO5U1)  i'm not in any position to check them out now, but someone else might be able to.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Madam the Linkedin link is not working as it might need a login and pwd. if you can provide a open link pl add it above to gather them at one place.

Comment: a corrected url was posted earlier today in a comment.  it points to a playlist on youtube:  (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4B8Cmm9scmU&feature=share&list=PLnC5h3PY-znygZ2rYNaX7_8j2Duwh58cK)  -- i hope this comes through okay.